# Access violation when closing program in OSX32

Tags: delphi, debugging, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

When I close my program while debugging my OSX program, I get an AccessViolation. It breaks at following point: in `System.internals.ExcUtils`

```
procedure RaiseSignalException(ExceptionEIP: LongWord; FaultAddr: LongWord; ErrorCode: LongWord);
begin
  raise GetExceptionObject(ExceptionEIP, FaultAddr, ErrorCode);
end;
```

Explaination given:

> RaiseSignalException is called from SignalConverter, once we've made things look
>         like there's a legitimate stack frame above us.  Now we will just create
>         an exception object, and raise it via a software raise.

Should I try to resolve this, because the acces violation is fired when closing the program and the program does not hang when not debugging?

**Edit :** 
I do get this error even while not debugging on the PA server. But the error remains the same.

Comment: RaiseSignalException is just a final point of an exception. Look at the Call Stack to find out more reasonable routine where app fails.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should definitely try to resolve that. Even though you now "only" see that error when closing your application, it could likely point to a more severe problem in your application that could also happen during runtime. Just imagine that this error happens because of a memory corruption during runtime.

Hint: Try using FastMM4 with the debug options enabled.

Comment: Sebastian, I'm now using FASTMM in my prgram, but I need to know where the Memoryleak report is saved."Memory leak detail is logged to same folder as this application". But I haven't found it. Is this on the Mac or on the PC?

Comment: Both, Win and Mac. When running on the Mac, the report will be saved into the application package on the Mac. Right-click the application, then "Show Package Contents". It will be in the MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS folder.

Comment: Ok, I found the folder in user/paserver/scratchdir/user/Myaplication.app/contents/macOs/. But i ony find 3 files : -application, -application.rsm and libcgwind.

Comment: You will not get the memory leak report if the application crashes before it gets written. Also some Delphi versions "kill" the application without executing the finalization parts. That is also problematic for writing the report.